# Invalid string or buffer length connecting to SQL database from netbeans

Tags: sql-server, netbeans, odbc

I am trying to connect to a SQL server database from Netbeans 7.2.1, but get this error: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Invalid string or buffer length

There seems to be something wrong with my connection, but I can't find what. The data source is tested and works.

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    try{
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:school");
        Statement st = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select 'hello'");
        while(rs.next()) {
            System.out.println(rs.getString(0));
    }
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Does anyone know why? Grateful for help!

Comment: At first why do you not use JDBC driver for SQL Server? Can you also show stack trace? And if you really want to use ODBC then enable ODBC Trace in ODBC Administrator and check what was call made by JDBC-ODBC bridge resulted with that error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe it would better to use native JDBC driver?
You can download it from: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=21599

There is also some info that in Java8 ODBC bridge will be removed: https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=7176225

Comment: Yes, did this and now it works! I'm not certain, but think my problem had something to do with me being on a 64-bit system and netbeans not communicating well to my 64-bit odbc bridge. Or something completely different. However, works now with jdbc!